# Google push-to-deploy release pipeline disabled?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jenkins, google-compute-engine, google-app-engine-python

I do have got a small Python application running on Google App Engine. For a while I did use Google's push-to-deploy feature, which automatically deployed the app once I pushed a new version of the master branch to my bitbucket git-repository.

I recently renamed my repository and noticed that the Release Pipeline in Google's Developer Console is not working anymore. Instead of being able to add a simple release pipeline I got the following message:

> See [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy?hl=en_US) for information on how to set up Jenkins,
>   and configure continuous deployment for your GCP apps.

- How can I take advantage of the simple push-to-deploy solution again?
- Is there an advantage of using Jenkins? As far as I understood I would now have to subscribe for a Google Compute Engine instance which does run Jenkins for me. But I wanted to stay away from maintaining VMs.

Comment: I am dealing with the new jenkins setup right now and the startup script fails to the initialization VM so you end up with a broken jenkins box. The whole process is broken right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a product manager for Google Cloud. 
Based on comprehensive customer feedback and evaluation we don't believe
that Push to Deploy meets the expectations and needs for most of our customers. We want to provide great quality, sustainable products to customers that meet the needs of the vast majority of our users. We were told that the option for the many customers who requested more control was the Jenkins route.
As such, we are going to continue to investigate how to satisfy customers
who want simpler solutions like Push to Deploy and will keep you posted as we make progress.

Comment: Hi Rae, it looks like this is the correct answer. I hope you keep us posted when you do enable push-to-deploy again.

Comment: While it is great that you are catering to customer needs, stopping existing functionality that too in a short notice stumbles developers and puts existing system in jeopardy which depends on this feature